# Mapping Python list based on dict value

Tags: python

I want to map python list based on values of dict. I know how to do that when I have pandas series, but I do not know how to do it with list:

```
l = ['apple', 'lemmon', 'banana']
x = {'apple':1, 'lemmon':2, 'banana':3, 'chery':4}

l = l.map(x)
print(l)
```

Desired output:

```
l = [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved with Python list comprehensions.
In your case:

```
l = [x[key] for key in l]
```

Note that all elements in `l` need to exist as keys in `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `dict.get` method and the `map` builtin:

```py
m = list(map(x.get, l))
```

Note that elements of `l` that are not keys of `x` will be mapped to `None`.

Answer (score 2):

With a comprehension:

```
>>> [x.get(i) for i in l]
[1, 2, 3]
```